# ASP.NET Core Application Initialization on Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to implement Application Initialization (warm up) on an ASP.NET Core web app running on Azure, as described for IIS 8.
The way it's described is changing web.confg to enable and configure it.
But in asp.net core we (almost) don't have web.config.
So, how do we configure Application Initialization (or any other feature that require
changing web.config)?

Comment: @PedroG.Dias I know web.config is gone that's why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out, for this question and any other that requires IIS to be configured through web.config:

It's not true there isn't web.config anymore. It's true that it doesn't play any role in the asp.net core app, but you can find a small web.config file in wwwroot project folder, which is what tells IIS how to handle the asp.net core app.

So for implementing this, or for example urlrewrite, you just need to add IIS configuration to that web.config file as it's being deployed as part of the application.